# CococaPods: List all versions of a pod ever released and see version history

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, cocoapods

I have this pod in my Podfile:

```
pod 'Cartography', '~> 0.6.0’
```

I want to know how I can find out about all versions of this Pod that have ever been released. The end goal is to see if I can find a version that is written in Swift 2.3 (released June 12, 2016) so I can upgrade the pod from XCode 7 to XCode 8. I don't necessarily want the latest version - I want one that is going to work with Swift 2.3

[Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/?q=cartog) shows that the most recent version is 0.7.0

How can I see a history of all released versions and the date of when they were released?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this helps you. Check out the GitHub page of the pod.

https://github.com/robb/Cartography/releases

You can test each version and see if it works with 2.3, but in most pods the developer will write a comment of compatibility in the description of the release.

Comment: I didn't realize all those github projects had that release tab - thank you @rcpfuchs. What if the project is not hosted on github, such as Fabric and Crashlytics ? How do I get the version history for those ?

Comment: Just a quick thought: Not every release is necessarily a CocoaPods release.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you really want is doing a `pod search Cartography`. This gives you the release history of given pod, not release history of source code, just as HAS has mentioned in comment.

Ref: [CococaPods: List all versions of a pod ever released and see version history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39517455/cococapods-list-all-versions-of-a-pod-ever-released-and-see-version-history)

Comment: Is there a way to view the cocoa pods page? I'm having a hard time figuring out version dependencies of a previous version...